# SSL Handshake error while using Glue to connect to a RDS

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-vpc, aws-rds-data-service

I am trying to extract data an AWS RDS. This RDS is in different account and VPC. When I am testing the connection it is showing successful. Also my Glue crawler can crawl the data successfully. But when I am running a glue job with same connection, I am getting a SSL handshake error. RDS is using mysql, and had the certificate 'rds-ca-rsa2048-g1' but reverted back to 'rds-ca-2019'.